# Setting up Apache Kafka Cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I've been experimenting with Apache Kafka, the distributed streaming platform, but I'm having difficulties with the "distributed" aspect of it.

I'm using the example [here](https://github.com/kmhoran/DistributedStreamingWithPythonAndKafka), which works fine when everything is on the same machine. But I wanna run it as a cluster with 2 or more VMs

What I managed to do so far:

- Setting up the VMs properly with Host-Only adapters.
- Setting up Zookeeper cluster (Quorum mode as pointed out by [Rajkumar Natarajan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2541276/rajkumar-natarajan)) by adding the following to `/etc/zookeeper/conf/zoo.fcg`:

  ```
  server.1=192.168.56.101:2888:3888
  server.2=192.168.56.102:2888:3888
  ```

  and making sure `myid` from `/var/lib/zookeeper` is unique for each server. Running `bin/zkServer.sh status` gives one `Mode: leader` and `Mode: follower` for the rest as it should.
- Setting up Kafka cluster by changing the following in `config/server.properties`:

  ```
  broker.id=0 # 1 for the second server
  zookeeper.connect=192.168.56.101:2181,192.168.56.102:2181
  ```
- Setting up a sonsumer in Python:

  ```
  from kafka import KafkaConsumer
  consumer = KafkaConsumer(
      topic, 
      bootstrap_servers=['192.168.56.101:9092','192.168.56.102:9092'])
  ```
- Setting up a producer in Python:

  ```
  from kafka import KafkaProducer
  producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='192.168.56.101:9092,192.168.56.102:9092')
  ```

What I want to do:

Configure my Kafka in a way that allows me to run 2 or more brokers on different VMs as a cluster.

My setup:

- Host: Windows 10 (1803) with VirtualBox 5.2.20
- Guests: Ubuntu 18.04, Kafka 2.0.0

Comment: One thing I want to point out here is Zookeeper Quoram shoud be odd numbers. Also your question is not very clear what you mean by "Configure my Kafka in a way that allows it to run in one VM with the consumer and/or producer running on different VMs." If you can connect to guest VMs from host machine by 'ping' or 'telnet' then you can access it KAFKA_FOLDER/bin/kafka-producer.sh

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, now reading it again I see that it wasn't clear, the correct way to put it is: have 2 or more Kafka brokers running on different machines as a cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me some time to find the solution since most tutorials stop short of the clustering part or showcase it on one single machine instead of several ones:

All that needs to be done is adding this line to `config/server.properties`:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.56.101:9092 # for broker.id=0
listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.56.102:9092 # for broker.id=1
```

Comment: You should be able to use `PLAINTEXT://:9092`, by the way. The advertised listeners config is a more important one for client connections

Comment: `PLAINTEXT://:9092` didn't work for me, but that could be due to other configuration mistakes at that point. I'll try again and see.
Is there any downside for letting the advertised listeners default to using the same listerner's config? because I thought that's what happens.

Comment: The listeners setting is called a "bind address" - what the server "listens on". The **advertised** listeners are how the **clients** know how to reach the other brokers that are not part of the `bootstrap.servers` configuration. For example, you have three Kafka servers, and your client only mentions one. The client needs to be able to find the leader(s) for the topic partitions that it is interested in, then connect to those addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I have cluster setup using vagrant box.
This has 3 machines using zookeeper installed in it in quorom mode.
And 3 kafka brokers in it and one machine with kafka manager and another machine with kafka registry.

All you have to do it download it and do `vagrant up`.

https://github.com/rajcspsg/VBoxes/blob/master/kafka-platform-centos/Vagrantfile

Comment: I'll try this soon and report the results.

Comment: Thanks, this answer wasn't exactly suitable for my use case, but it gave me some insight on where to start. more info in the updated question and the answer.

Comment: @HUSMEN Using Vagrant is usually preferred over manual VM set-up. Even here, I have a branch that setups all of the Confluent Platform in just a few commands https://github.com/cricket007/cp-ansible/blob/addVagrant/vagrant/README.md

Comment: I see, this makes Vagrant the next thing to learn for me then.